# Nesting Foreach loop inside Foreach loop using short_open_tags

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, custom-fields, php-shorttags

I have the following foreach loop:

```
<?php
    $fields = CFS()->get('list-item-field');
?>
    <? foreach ($fields as $field) : ?>

        <?= $field['list-item-title'] ?>    

    <? endforeach ?>
```

And I would like to add another foreach inside the loop, like so:

```
<?php
    $fields = CFS()->get('item-field');
?>
    <? foreach ($fields as $field) : ?>

        <?= $field['list-item-title'] ?>

        <?php
            $values = CFS()->get('color');
        ?>
            <? foreach ($values as $value => $label) : ?>
                <? echo $value ; ?>
            <? endforeach ?>

    <? endforeach ?>
```

However this doesn't work, and I get the error:

> Invalid Argument Supplied For Foreach()

Comment: whatever `$values = CFS()->get('color');` is returning it is not an array. Do a var_dump($values) to check what type/value it is.

Comment: It's the shortcode that's intended to retrieve a single item from an array: http://customfieldsuite.com/docs/select/

Comment: The foreach loop for the color works when it's not nested within the other foreach..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright I needed to expirement a bit but I figured it out, I doubt this will be helpful to many but regardless here's what I needed to do:

```
<?php
    $fields = CFS()->get('item-field');
?>
    <? foreach ($fields as $field) : ?>

        <?= $field['list-item-title'] ?>

        <? foreach ($field['color'] as $colors => $label) :?>
            <? echo $colors ; ?>
        <? endforeach ?>

    <? endforeach ?>
```

This post helped: http://customfieldsuite.com/forums/questions/925/loop-within-a-loop